# typescript --out compile smaller namespace generation

Tags: typescript

Right now when i specify a lot of files to compile down, files in the same namespace get generated:

```
var NS1;
(function (NS1) {
    (function (NS2) {
       //...
    })(NS1.NS2 || (NS1.NS2 = {}));
    var NS2 = NS1.NS2;
})(NS1 || (NS1 = {}));
var NS1;
(function (NS1) {
    (function (NS2) {
       //...
    })(NS1.NS2 || (NS1.NS2 = {}));
    var NS2 = NS1.NS2;
})(NS1 || (NS1 = {}));
```

There is quite a lot of redundancy.
Is there a command or tool to further reduce this namespace into one namespace call?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. The easiest solution is to move all the module items into one declaration